# Angular 2.0, observable goes into error callback even with a valid response

Tags: angular, http, subscribe

Currently working on Angular 2.0 on client side and Spring Boot on server side.
When I send a http post request from client to server , server takes 5-6 mins to send a response because of some procedure calls. 
But when the response comes and I try to subscribe it, it goes into error callback.
When I see it on the chrome networks tab, the preview and response tab shows my correct response which I expect, but subscribe sends it to error callback. I don't know how this happens?
FYI, my json response is a huge json.

{code}

```
onSubmit() {
        this.service.Service(this.model).subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.Table = data; 
          console.log(this.Table);
        },
        error => console.log("Inside error clause " + error.statusText + " Error " + error.error));         
  }
```

My service call
{code}

```
Service(data : Data) :Observable<any>{

    //console.log(data);

    return this.http.post(this.URL_Forms,data,httpOptions).share();

  }
```

Can you anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `.share();` why this method is there ?

Comment: @PranayRana because I multiple subscribers for the observable

Comment: Did you try changing timeout? `.post(...).timeout(500000)`.share()?`

Comment: @David Tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you analyse the error argument provided in the callback? What does it say?